# how to inject <template> into polymer component by providing it as element content

Tags: polymer

i want to inject a template into an polymer component like this :

```
<polymer-element name="foo-bar">
  <template>
    <content></content>
    <!-- content is expected to contain a template with id="layout"-->
    <template bind ref="layout">
      default content template
    </template>
  </template>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

usage of the component :

```
<foo-bar>
    <template id="layout">another content template</template>
</foo-bar>
```

unfortunately the template provided as content of the  element is not taken over for some reason.

when simluate the wished behaviour using

```
<polymer-element name="foo-bar">
  <template>
    <template id="layout">
      custom content template
    </template>
    <template bind ref="layout">
      default content template
    </template>
  </template>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

the referenced template(id="layout") is used as expected.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<template ref="layout">` [says](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#importing-templates-by-reference) use the template#layout for my content. So I would expect the template in your shadow dom to use the content of the light dom template. This is what you see in http://jsbin.com/takipi/1/edit.

However, if you want to use render the light dom `<template>` the user provides, you must activate it using `template.createInstance()`. By default, templates are inert. For this use case, you also don't need `<content>`. That's for rendering and in this case, it doesn't really make sense.

The example below also show how to set things up. It also shows how you can use `{{}}` bindings in the light dom `<template>` and fill them when the instance is created.

```
<div id="container"></div>

<template if="{{showDefault}}">
  default content template
</template>

attached: function() {
  var template = this.querySelector('template');
  if (template) {
      this.$.container.appendChild(
          template.createInstance({foo: 5}));
      this.showDefault = false;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>
  
<polymer-element name="foo-bar">
  <template>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <template if="{{showDefault}}">
      default content template
    </template>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      showDefault: true,
      attached: function() {
        var template = this.querySelector('template');
        if (template) {
          // Allow Polymer expressions in the template's {{}}.
          if (!template.bindingDelegate) {
            template.bindingDelegate = this.element.syntax;
          }

          this.$.container.appendChild(
              template.createInstance({foo: 5}));
          
          this.showDefault = false;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<foo-bar>
  <template>
    <b>another</b> content template. Also supports data: {{foo}}
  </template>
</foo-bar>
```

Comment: very helpful - thank you !! but your jsbin example brings me to my next problem : if i move the foo-bar polymer element definition into an external (html) file and import it in the main html file, the <template  id="layout"> element provided within <foo-bar> is again not used and the output again "default content template". Any ideas ?

Comment: That's because the template is in another document. This should help: http://jsbin.com/robemu/1/edit. The source `<template id="layout>` is in another import: http://jsbin.com/cideb/1/edit. That import automatically adds the template to the main document so others can use it using `document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('template#layout'), true));`